# Kafka Docker, docker-maven-plugin, Spring Boot

Tags: docker, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, maven-docker-plugin

I'm trying to start Kafka via Docker Maven Plugin https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin

I use the following Maven image: https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/

This is my Maven config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${docker-maven-plugin.version}</version>

    <configuration>
        <showLogs>true</showLogs>

        <images>
            <image>
                <name>wurstmeister/kafka:1.0.0</name>
                <alias>kafka</alias>
                <run>
                    <ports>
                        <port>9092:9092</port>
                    </ports>
                </run>

            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-containers</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>remove-containers</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The output of `mvn docker:start -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` command:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building domain 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.22.1:start (default-cli) @ domain ---
[INFO] DOCKER> [wurstmeister/kafka:1.0.0] "kafka": Start container b89836e54566
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.022 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-22T11:52:24+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/514M
```

I'm trying to use Kafka from my Spring Boot application but I unable to send any messages to the topic and in the DEBUG mode it shows me the following errors:

```
2017-11-22 11:55:52.548 DEBUG 8032 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Node -1 disconnected.
2017-11-22 11:55:52.548  WARN 8032 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2017-11-22 11:55:52.548 DEBUG 8032 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Give up sending metadata request since no node is available
2017-11-22 11:55:52.599 DEBUG 8032 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Initialize connection to node -1 for sending metadata request
2017-11-22 11:55:52.599 DEBUG 8032 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : Initiating connection to node -1 at localhost:9092.
2017-11-22 11:55:53.166 DEBUG 8032 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.PlaintextTransportLayer.finishConnect(PlaintextTransportLayer.java:50) ~[kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.finishConnect(KafkaChannel.java:95) ~[kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:359) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:326) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:432) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:232) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:208) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:199) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:134) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:223) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:200) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:286) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1078) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1043) [kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:571) [spring-kafka-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
```

What am I ding wrong and how to properly configure Kafka container ?

**UPDATED**

> docker logs 033b48f6360a

```
waiting for kafka to be ready
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,049] INFO KafkaConfig values:
        advertised.host.name = null
        advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://:9092
        advertised.port = null
        alter.config.policy.class.name = null
        authorizer.class.name =
        auto.create.topics.enable = true
        auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
        background.threads = 10
        broker.id = -1
        broker.id.generation.enable = true
        broker.rack = null
        compression.type = producer
        connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
        controlled.shutdown.enable = true
        controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
        controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
        controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        create.topic.policy.class.name = null
        default.replication.factor = 1
        delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
        delete.topic.enable = true
        fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
        group.max.session.timeout.ms = 300000
        group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
        host.name =
        inter.broker.listener.name = null
        inter.broker.protocol.version = 1.0-IV0
        leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
        leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
        listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
        listeners = PLAINTEXT://:9092
        log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
        log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
        log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
        log.cleaner.enable = true
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
        log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
        log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
        log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
        log.cleaner.threads = 1
        log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
        log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
        log.dirs = /kafka/kafka-logs-033b48f6360a
        log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.interval.ms = null
        log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
        log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
        log.message.format.version = 1.0-IV0
        log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
        log.preallocate = false
        log.retention.bytes = -1
        log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
        log.retention.hours = 168
        log.retention.minutes = null
        log.retention.ms = null
        log.roll.hours = 168
        log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
        log.roll.jitter.ms = null
        log.roll.ms = null
        log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
        log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
        max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
        max.connections.per.ip.overrides =
        message.max.bytes = 1000012
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        min.insync.replicas = 1
        num.io.threads = 8
        num.network.threads = 3
        num.partitions = 1
        num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
        num.replica.fetchers = 1
        offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
        offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
        offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
        offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
        offsets.retention.minutes = 1440
        offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
        offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
        offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
        offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
        port = 9092
        principal.builder.class = null
        producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        queued.max.request.bytes = -1
        queued.max.requests = 500
        quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.window.num = 11
        quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
        replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
        replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
        replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
        replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
        replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
        replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
        replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        replication.quota.window.num = 11
        replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
        sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
        security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
        socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
        socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.client.auth = none
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
        transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
        transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
        transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
        transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
        transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
        transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
        transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
        unclean.leader.election.enable = false
        zookeeper.connect =
        zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
        zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
        zookeeper.set.acl = false
        zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,118] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,120] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on  (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,132] INFO Starting ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,139] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.10-39d3a4f269333c922ed3db283be479f9deacaa0f, built on 03/23/2017 10:13 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,139] INFO Client environment:host.name=033b48f6360a (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_144 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:java.home=/opt/jdk1.8.0_144/jre (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.5.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-api-1.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-file-1.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-json-1.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-1.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-1.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/guava-20.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0-b32.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0-b32.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.9.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.9.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.9.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.9.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.9.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.9.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.inject-1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.inject-2.5.0-b32.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.25.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.25.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.25.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-guava-2.25.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.25.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.25.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-1.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-1.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-1.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-1.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-1.0.0-sources.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-1.0.0-test-sources.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/kafka_2.12-1.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/lz4-java-1.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/maven-artifact-3.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/plexus-utils-3.0.24.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.11.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.7.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.12.3.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.4.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zkclient-0.10.jar:/opt/kafka/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.4.10.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:os.version=4.9.49-moby (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:user.name=root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:user.home=/root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,140] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,141] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString= sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@1534f01b (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,150] INFO Waiting for keeper state SyncConnected (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,152] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-11-22 11:59:35,156] WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
[2017-11-22 11:59:36,259] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-11-22 11:59:36,260] WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
[2017-11-22 11:59:37,360] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-11-22 11:59:37,361] WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
[2017-11-22 11:59:38,463] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-11-22 11:59:38,463] WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
[2017-11-22 11:59:39,564] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-11-22 11:59:39,565] WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
[2017-11-22 11:59:40,668] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-11-22 11:59:40,668] WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141)
[2017-11-22 11:59:41,151] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2017-11-22 11:59:41,769] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-11-22 11:59:41,874] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-11-22 11:59:41,876] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server '' with timeout of 6000 ms
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1233)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:157)
        at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:131)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:115)
        at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.withMetrics(ZkUtils.scala:92)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:350)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:194)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:92)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2017-11-22 11:59:41,877] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-11-22 11:59:41,876] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-11-22 11:59:41,891] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-11-22 11:59:41,892] FATAL Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2017-11-22 11:59:41,895] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Comment: Can you try to telnet and see if you can reach kafka ? Also by default spring kafka looks for kafka running on `localhost:9092` , make sure that you are using correct `docker IP` when bootstrapping the application.

Comment: I'm unable to telnet to localhost 9092

Comment: What may be wrong with my Docker config there?

Comment: Also, what is the correct wait condition I can use in order to check that Docker container is started properly?

Comment: You can check via`docker ps`, once you see the kafka container than check its IP using docker inspect (look under network settings)`docker inspect <containerID>`

Comment: I have added the logs. looks like my Kafka container dies because of no ZooKeeper found... I think I have to configure another container for ZooKeeper also, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, indeed zookeeper seems to be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [sol4me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1707520/sol4me) and [sanath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3514821/sanath) for your comments and ideas.

Finally, I managed to run Kafka + Zookeeper with Docker Maven Plugin without docker-compose in the following manner:

```
<image>
    <name>wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest</name>
    <alias>zookeeper</alias>
    <run>
        <ports>
            <port>2181:2181</port>
        </ports>
    </run>
</image>

<image>
    <name>wurstmeister/kafka:1.0.0</name>
    <alias>kafka</alias>
    <run>
        <ports>
            <port>9092:9092</port>
        </ports>
        <links>
            <link>zookeeper:zookeeper</link>
        </links>
        <env>
            <KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>127.0.0.1</KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME>
            <KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>zookeeper:2181</KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT>
        </env>
    </run>
</image>
```

Answer (score 1):

yes issues is with zookeeper, above image which is been used for kafka it meant to be run with the compose which has linking of all the dependent server.either you have to use docker-compose maven plugin and refer this link for deployment
https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker

or you can modify the standalone dockerfile mentioned in above link to start the zookeeper server before calling "start-kafka.sh"